# python pygame mask collision

Tags: python, pygame, mask

when I try to use this piece of code, it only works for 1 object, not for every.
I'm trying to modify code from this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Idu8XfwKUao). Is there is a simpler way to get a result ?.If there is,please let me know

```
#part of code that doesn't matter
randomx = [100,400,300]
randomy = [100,0,300]
green_blob = pygame.image.load("greenblob-59x51.png").convert_alpha()
orange_blob = pygame.image.load("orangeblob-59x51.png").convert_alpha()
blob_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(green_blob)
blob_color = green_blob
obstacle = []
obstacle_mask = []
oy = []
ox = []
for i in range(4):
    obstacle.append(pygame.image.load("obstacle-400x399.png").convert_alpha())
    obstacle_mask.append(pygame.mask.from_surface(obstacle[i]))
    ox.append(random.choice(randomx))
    oy.append(random.choice(randomy))
# main loop
while True:
    events()
    for i in range(4):
        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        offset = ((mx - int(ox[i]))), ((my - int(oy[i])))
        result = obstacle_mask[i].overlap(blob_mask, offset)
        if result:
            blob_color = orange_blob
        else:
            blob_color = green_blob
        screen.blit(obstacle[i], (ox[i], oy[i]))
        screen.blit(blob_color, (mx, my))



    pygame.display.update()
    CLOCK.tick(FPS)
    screen.fill(BLACK)
```

Comment: Which bit of code is not working? If some of the code is irrelevant to the issue then remove it

Comment: As a follow-up to what @IainShelvington wrote, please see: [mcve]. I'm voting to close this as there is no clear and specific problem statement, and no way to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @IainShelvington That's the problem, program works, and it draws 4 obstacles, but only 1 has got hitboxes

Comment: @witolo where are you testing the hitboxes?

Comment: @IainShelvington nevermind, the solution from Rabbid76 works as charm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application works fine. The issue is, that result of each evaluation of `overlap` cause a change of `blob_color`. So the last obstacle in the loop "wins". If the last obstacle `overlaps` the blob, then the color is `orange_blob`, else it is `green_blob`.
Set the green color before the loop. If any obstacle `overlaps` the blob, then change it to orange. The blob has to be drawn once after the loop. e.g.:

```py
while True:
    events()

    blob_color = green_blob
    for i in range(4):
        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        offset = (int(mx - ox[i]), int(my - oy[i]))
        if obstacle_mask[i].overlap(blob_mask, offset):
            blob_color = orange_blob

        screen.blit(obstacle[i], (ox[i], oy[i]))

    screen.blit(blob_color, (mx, my))
```

[image]

---

To find obstacle at random positions, which are not overlapping, you have to evaluate if a new obstacle hits any of the former obstacles.
Create a random position:

```py
x, y = random.randint(100, 400), random.randint(100, 400)
```

And evaluate if there is [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) obstacle that `overlap`s the new position.

```py
isect = any(obstacle_mask[j].overlap(obstacle_mask[i], (x-ox[j], y-oy[j])) for j in range(i))
```

If that is the case, then repeat the process. Create a new random position and test for overlapping:

```py
obstacle = []
obstacle_mask = []
oy = []
ox = []
for i in range(4):
    obstacle.append(pygame.image.load("obstacle-400x399.png").convert_alpha())
    obstacle_mask.append(pygame.mask.from_surface(obstacle[i]))

    isect = True
    while isect:
        x, y = random.randint(100, 400), random.randint(100, 400)
        isect = any(obstacle_mask[j].overlap(obstacle_mask[i], (x-ox[j], y-oy[j])) for j in range(i))

    ox.append(x)
    oy.append(y)
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that my mistake was so silly